# eval() not working for matrix names

Tags: matlab, eval

```
a1=[1 2 3];
a2=[1 2 3];
i=2;
//below, I'm trying to check if size(a1,2) ~= size(a2,2)
if size(a1,2) ~= size(eval(['a' num2str(i)]),2),
disp('columns not equal');
else
disp('columns equal');
end
```

The above code displays "columns not equal", when the columns *are* equal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Strange...I copy-pasted the above code onto the Matlab command-line and it still printed "columns not equal" when it should've printed "columns equal". There's something wrong. Please help.

Comment: What version of Matlab do you use? What happens if you change it to `eval(['size(a' num2str(i) ',2)'])` ?

Comment: what does `eval(['a' num2str(i)])` output on the command window after you run the code

Comment: Works for me too. Perhaps you are running an older version of Matlab? Mine is 2010b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code in MATLAB R2010b, I get the correct results. Here are some things you should check:

- Try [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html) instead of [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html) (I'm guessing it's *not* the source of the problem, but check just to be sure).
- Issue a [`clear all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html) command to clear the main workspace, then try running your code again. This will rule out any chance that you are shadowing the functions `eval`, `size`, or `num2str` with a local variable.
- Check to see if you're shadowing `eval`, `size`, or `num2str` with a user-defined function by using the [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) command. For example, this will show you all of the overloaded versions of `eval` that currently exist:

  ```
  which eval -all
  ```
- If you are still having problems, find out which [MATLAB version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ver.html) you are using and see if a bug report involving the [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) function already exists on [this MathWorks support page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/) (**NOTE:** you need a MathWorks account login to access the bug reports).

Comment: Err...it's working now. I think the problem really was the existence of some old a1 or a2 array which was larger than what I defined. If that was the case, I'm surprised the new array I defined didn't override the old one. Anyway, I had closed matlab and opened it again and the problem didn't happen any more. Then again, it couldn't be a problem with the a1 and a2 arrays. eval wasn't working for a lot of other arrays. Anyway, it's all miraculously working now. Thanks.